# Are there any cheat sheets listing all the cars in GTA 4, with images?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

Does anyone have a list with images of all cars in GTA IV (commenly called a cheat-sheet).

I saw one once, but that was 2 computers ago, and I can't find it.

Comment: This is a list-form question, and is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE Delusional Logic, unfortunatly list-form questions aer off-topic here, and this question will very likely be closed before long. Please read our FAQ for more information. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @Ender I don't actually see any big problem with this question. Questions that ask for a finite list of things are okay as long as the scope is reasonable. You can read more [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/865/how-large-can-an-objective-questions-scope-get) and [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/list-questions-for-the-old-republic-mmos-cw-closure-other). I personally think the scope is reasonable here, and that this is a very useful question :)

Comment: @Oak Thank you for correcting me, I was under the impression for quite some time now (months) that LISTS of just about any sort were off-topic here. And I distinctly (although I might be wrong, and can't find the passage now) remember the FAQ specifying that lists were offtopic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [a useful list on gta4.net](http://www.gta4.net/vehicles/). It provides a list of all vehicles with some basic data (top speed, breaking, etc.), and next to each vehicle is a small camera icon which will display an image of that vehicle when you hover over it.

Another [useful list is available on ign](http://grandtheftauto.ign.com/wiki/GTA_IV_Vehicles), select a category to see a page with a list of all the vehicles under that category, their attributes and a screenshot.